# Selecting elements from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, data, filtering

I have the following array of numbers:

```
a = {{0, 2, 5}, {3, 5, 1}, {4, 0, 5}, {8, 3, 4}, {0, 8, 6}};
```

then I make a list of the first row with

```
r = a[[All, 1]]
```

I would like to take just the elements where the first number is equal to 0. I have tried with

```
TakeWhile[a, r = 0]
```

but I didn't get a result.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: a[[All, 1]] isn't the first row, it's the first column

Answer (score 1):

You might try

```
Cases[a,{0,__}]
(* {{0, 2, 5}, {0, 8, 6}} *)
```

Comment: @GregorioMartinez: You're most welcome. Please also accept my answer, if it fits your needs.